# Drive power supply straight to Peltier (TEC)

Tags: power-supply, peltier

Can I clip the output wires of a 12V power supply to the wires on a Peltier (TEC) module?
http://www.customthermoelectric.com/tecs/pdf/00711-5L31-03CA_spec_sht.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet says the maximum voltage is 0.85 volts, so NO!!

You would destroy the Peltier module if you applied 12 volts.

Comment: I forgot to note that there are several resistors and other components linked to the module. (http://i.imgur.com/lDg6mQA.jpg) From left to right, the inputs are: output to Peltier(+), power(+), return from TEC(-), power ground, control ground, control signal. The controls are for Arduino MOSFET control.

Comment: Is it possible for a bunch of resistors/regulators to allow a 12V power supply to drive this Peltier? I was handed down this project, and I was told that a 12V power supply would drive it.

Comment: Revise your question to include a schematic or description of the control circuit, as that will probably change the answer.  By the way, I've seen a couple of comments recently on here that it is not good to drive a Peltier device with PWM.

Comment: Considering how low resistance most TECs are, I think destroying the power supply is far more likely, assuming it doesn't have short-circuit output protection.

Comment: Dropping almost 11V at 3A through a resistor is going to be nasty - it will dissipate 33W of heat. You would need a power resistor connected to a big heatsink, or it would all burn in seconds.